# Using Rails html tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am wondering if i can use rails tags in html using jquery to reload a table based on a new query. See below:

```
    <table id = "PlyrsTm2" style = float:right>
        <tr><th id="PTTitle" colspan=2>List of players on selected team</th></tr>
        <tr><th id="PTHRows">Player</th><th id="PTHRows">Team</th></tr>
        <% @pl.each do |f| %>
            <tr><td class="player"><%= f.Plyr %></td><td class="team"><%= f.Team %></td></tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
```

So i know that i can do this:

```
$('#PlyrsTm2').html('<table id = "PlyrsTm2" style = float:right><tr><th id="PTTitle" colspan=2>List of players on selected team</th></tr><tr><th id="PTHRows">Player</th><th id="PTHRows">Team</th></tr><tr><td class="player"></td><td class="team"></td></tr></table>
```

but if I add the rails part to it, then it does not refresh/reload the table. I have looked all over the internet and have not found the solution. I posted a question similar to this, but no one answered and it was voted down because of not enough research(which is not true) because i only post questions to answer that i do not find so can someone help me with this, i would greatly appreciated

**RE-UPDATED**

it might be helpful to post the ajax and jquery that i am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showbtn').on('click', function() {
        ids = $('#teams').val()
        IM = false
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/teamplayers.json?resolution="+ids+"&import="+IM,
        type:"get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success:function(data){
            $('#PlyrsTm2').html(data);
                $('#PlyrsTm2').show();
            alert(data);
            alert("Loading Players...."); 
            },
        error: function(error) {
                   alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error)
                   }           
                   });
                $('#PlyrsTm2').trigger('create');


            });


});
```

I click a button (#showbtn) which it passes a integer value (#teams) to my controller, which is then changed and here is the table i want it to load:

```
'<table id = "PlyrsTm2" style = float:right><tr><th id="PTTitle" colspan=2>List of players on selected team</th></tr><tr><th id="PTHRows">Player</th><th id="PTHRows">Team</th></tr><tr><% @pl.each do |f| %><td class="player"><%= f.Plyr %></td><td class="team"><%= f.Team %></td></tr><% end %></table>
```

As you can see there is Rails html in it, but i do not think it actually re-excutes the rails part `<& @pl.each do |f| %>`

which then i see the same table that loaded when the page was first opened. So how do i get the rails to re-execute with the new info?

I can post the controller method if needed.

**UPDATE**
Here is the controller

```
class TeamplayersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :set_id
    before_action :set_id, :set_teamplayer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /teamplayers
# GET /teamplayers.json
  def index
   @teamplayers = Teamplayer.all
   @fteams = Fteam.all

   tid = params[:resolution]
   toimport = params[:import]

   if tid.nil?
    tid = 1
   else
    tid = tid.to_i;
   end
   @ids = tid
   @pl =  Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).all << Here should refresh the table

   if toimport == "true"
    @turl = Fteam.where(:id => @ids).pluck(:TeamUrl)

    @turl = @turl[0]  

    system "rake updateTm:updateA[#{@turl},#{@ids}]"
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i looked at  your fiddle.

change this

```
        $('#SelectedTm').replaceWith(test2);
        },
    error: function(error) {
               alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error)
               }           
               });
$('#SelectedTm').trigger('create');
```

to this

```
    $('#SelectedTm').html(test2);
        $('#SelectedTm').trigger('create');
        },
    error: function(error) {
               alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error)
               }           
               });
```

Comment: Thanks this along with some maneuvering did exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

after this you have to de a trigger create like

$('#PlyrsTm2').trigger('create');

modify this

```
success:function(success){
            $('#PlyrsTm2').html(change1);
            alert("test 3"); 
            }
```

to this

```
success:function(data){
            $('#PlyrsTm2').html(data);
            $('#PlyrsTm2').trigger('create');
            }
```

Comment: it is reloading the same thing, let me update with what i have in my ajax/jquery

Comment: I posted where i put the trigger part, but it did not seem to do the trick

Comment: should i run the trigger inside or outside of the ajax?

Comment: Why is the trigger create not able to make use of the rails tags?

Comment: success:function(data){
            $('#PlyrsTm2').html(data);
            alert("test 3"); 
            },
        error: function(error) {
                   alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error)
                   }           
                   });
            $('#PlyrsTm2').trigger('create');

Comment: wait when i switched the option the table disappered why is that?

Comment: I clicked the button that triggers the click again and the table went away. I look in the view source and the table is still there but it is hidden

Comment: I have re-updated my ajax section. The only other code would by my controller and my rake file, I can post those in a few minutes

Comment: create a fiddle and i will have a look